# List not rendering even when the array is not empty and the state is not null

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve Game names from firestore and display in a list on the page.
For this I am using a component GameList(to display the names retrieved) and Home(to fetch and pass the retrieved data to GameList component).

Here is my code :
Home.js :-

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { personalDatabaseFirestore } from '../firebase/personalConfig';
import GameList from './GameList';
import './Home.css'

export default function Home(){

const [data, setData] = useState(null);


useEffect(()=>{

    const ref = personalDatabaseFirestore.collection('Games');
    let results = []

    const unsub = ref.onSnapshot((snapshot)=>{
        snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
            results.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id});
        })
    },(error)=>{
        console.log(error);
    })
    setData(results);
    return ()=>unsub();
},[]);

console.log(data);

return (
    <div className='mainpage-container'>
        {data && <GameList games={data}/>}
    </div>
);
```

}

GameList.js :-

```
export default function GameList({games}){
  console.log('game list recieved\n', games);
  return (
      <ul>
          {
              games.map((doc)=>{
                  return (<li key={doc.id}>{doc.name}</li>);
              })
          }
      </ul>
  )
}
```

Console screenshot shows that i am able to retrieve the data successfully from firestore and am able to pass it to GameList component too . But then after logging out the information in gameList component it is not rendering the list that it is supposed to return.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onSnapshot()` returns data asynchronously so you should use `setData` within it. That'll also ensure any data updates received later are also rendered. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const ref = personalDatabaseFirestore.collection('Games');
  
  const unsub = ref.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    const results = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }))
    setData(results);
  })
  return () => unsub();
}, []);
```

If you need to fetch data only once, then I'd recommend using `get()` instead of `onSnapshot`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const ref = personalDatabaseFirestore.collection('Games');

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const snapshot = await ref.get();
    const results = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
      id: doc.id,
      ...doc.data()
    }))
    setData(results);
  }
  
  fetchData();
}, []);
```